# Save Spark protobuf RDD to tfrecords

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark

I have a routine to save `tf.Example` protobuffs to tfrecords:

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("dataset.tfrecord") as writer:
     writer.write(proto)
```

I have a Spark RDD full of `tf.Example`s. I don't want to write them to disk using `saveAsTextFile`, I want to save them using the `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Spark-TFRecord.

Here is an example:

```
val df = Seq((8, "bat"),(8, "abc"), (1, "xyz"), (2, "aaa")).toDF("number", "word")
val tf_output_dir = "/tmp/tfrecord-test"
df.write.format("tfrecord").option("recordType", "Example").save(path)
```

You need to install spark-tfrecord. Details can be found at github repo: 
https://github.com/linkedin/spark-tfrecord